# Android BLE never receiving notifications from characteristics

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I've been struggling for quite a while now, trying to get my BLE device to communicate with my android app.

First off, here is my full code for BLE handling :

**BleCentral.java**

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;

public class BleCentral
{
    private HashMap<String, BluetoothGatt> m_connectedDevices;

    public BleCentral()
    {
        m_connectedDevices = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter m_GetAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        final BluetoothManager bleMgr = (BluetoothManager)(ctx.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE));
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = bleMgr.getAdapter();

        if (adapter == null || !adapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Log.e("BLE Central", "BLE either not available or not enabled. Please do something about it.");
            return null;
        }

        return adapter;
    }

    public BluetoothDevice GetDevice(Context ctx, String address)
    {
        return m_GetAdapter(ctx).getRemoteDevice(address);
    }

    public <T extends BlePeripheral>
    T Connect(Context ctx, String address, Supplier<T> supplier)
    {
        BluetoothDevice device = GetDevice(ctx, address);

        T result = supplier.get();
        m_connectedDevices.put(address, device.connectGatt(ctx, false, result, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE));

        return result;
    }
}
```

**BlePeripheral.java**

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;


public abstract class BlePeripheral
    extends BluetoothGattCallback
{
    private final String kCCC_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

    private Handler       m_handler;
    private boolean       m_deviceReady;
    private BluetoothGatt m_bluetoothGatt;

    private Queue<CmdQueueItem> m_cmdQueue;
    private boolean             m_cmdQueueProcessing;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Own methods

    protected BlePeripheral()
    {
        m_handler       = new Handler();
        m_deviceReady   = false;
        m_bluetoothGatt = null;

        m_cmdQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        m_cmdQueueProcessing = false;
    }

    public boolean IsDeviceReady()
    { return m_deviceReady; }

    public void EnableNotifications(UUID service, UUID characteristic)
    {  EnqueueSetNotificationForCharacteristic(m_bluetoothGatt.getService(service).getCharacteristic(characteristic), true); }

    public void DisableNotifications(UUID service, UUID characteristic)
    {  EnqueueSetNotificationForCharacteristic(m_bluetoothGatt.getService(service).getCharacteristic(characteristic), false); }

    protected void WriteCharacteristic(UUID service, UUID characteristic, byte[] value, boolean requestResponse)
    { EnqueueWriteCharacteristic(m_bluetoothGatt.getService(service).getCharacteristic(characteristic), value, requestResponse); }

    protected void ReadCharacteristic(UUID service, UUID characteristic)
    { EnqueueReadCharacteristic(m_bluetoothGatt.getService(service).getCharacteristic(characteristic)); }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- BluetoothGattCallback overrides

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState)
    {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

        final BluetoothDevice device = gatt.getDevice();

        switch (status)
        {
        case 133: /* GATT_ERROR */
            Log.e("BLE", "GATT_ERROR");
            gatt.close();

            try   { Thread.sleep(150); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            break;

        case 0: /* GATT_SUCCESS */
            switch (newState)
            {
            case BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.i("BLE", "Connected to " + device.getAddress() + " (" + device.getName() + ")");
                m_bluetoothGatt     = gatt;

                int delayWhenBonded = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) ? 2000 : 0;

                switch (device.getBondState())
                {
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
                    delayWhenBonded = 0;

                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
                    m_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            boolean result = gatt.discoverServices();
                            if (!result)
                                Log.e("BLE", "discoverServices() failed to start");
                        }
                    }, delayWhenBonded);
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
                    Log.i("BLE", "Waiting for bonding to complete");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                gatt.close();
                break;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)
    {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

        if (status == 129 /* GATT_INTERNAL_ERROR */)
        {
            Log.e("BLE", "Service discovery failed");
            gatt.disconnect();
            return;
        }

        final List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        Log.i("BLE", "Discovered " + services.size() + " services for " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());

        m_deviceReady   = SetupDevice(gatt);

        if (!m_deviceReady)
            Log.e("BLE", "Peripheral does not comply to this device's requirements");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
    {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);

        Log.i("BLE", "onCharacteristicChanged: " + characteristic.getUuid());
        final byte[] value = new byte[characteristic.getValue().length];
        System.arraycopy(characteristic.getValue(), 0, value, 0, characteristic.getValue().length);

        OnUpdate(characteristic.getService().getUuid(), characteristic.getUuid(), value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)
    {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

        ProcessCmdQueue();

        Log.i("BLE", "onCharacteristicRead: " + characteristic.getUuid());
        final byte[] value = new byte[characteristic.getValue().length];
        System.arraycopy(characteristic.getValue(), 0, value, 0, characteristic.getValue().length);

        OnUpdate(characteristic.getService().getUuid(), characteristic.getUuid(), value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)
    {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

        ProcessCmdQueue();

        Log.i("BLE", "onCharacteristicWrite: " + characteristic.getUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, final int status)
    {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);

        ProcessCmdQueue();

        final BluetoothGattCharacteristic parentCharacteristic = descriptor.getCharacteristic();

        if(status != 0 /* GATT_SUCCESS */)
        {
            Log.e("BLE", "WriteDescriptor failed for characteristic " + parentCharacteristic.getUuid());
            return;
        }

        if(descriptor.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString(kCCC_DESCRIPTOR_UUID)))
        {
            if(status == 0 /* GATT_SUCCESS */)
            {
                byte[] value = descriptor.getValue();
                if (value != null)
                {
                    if (value[0] != 0)
                        Log.i("BLE", "Characteristic " + parentCharacteristic.getUuid() + " is now notifying");
                    else
                        Log.i("BLE", "Characteristic " + parentCharacteristic.getUuid() + " is now NOT notifying");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Command Queue implementation

    /* An enqueueable write operation - notification subscription or characteristic write */
    private class CmdQueueItem
    {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
        byte[] dataToWrite; // Only used for characteristic write
        boolean writeWoRsp; // Only used for characteristic write
        boolean enabled;    // Only used for characteristic notification subscription
        public m_queueItemType type;
    }

    private enum m_queueItemType
    {
        SubscribeCharacteristic,
        ReadCharacteristic,
        WriteCharacteristic
    }

    /* queues enables/disables notification for characteristic */
    public void EnqueueSetNotificationForCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, boolean enabled)
    {
        // Add to queue because shitty Android GATT stuff is only synchronous
        CmdQueueItem m_queueItem    = new CmdQueueItem();
        m_queueItem.characteristic = ch;
        m_queueItem.enabled        = enabled;
        m_queueItem.type           = m_queueItemType.SubscribeCharacteristic;
        EnqueueBleCommand(m_queueItem);
    }

    /* queues enables/disables notification for characteristic */
    public void EnqueueWriteCharacteristic(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, final byte[] dataToWrite, boolean requestResponse)
    {
        // Add to queue because shitty Android GATT stuff is only synchronous
        CmdQueueItem m_queueItem    = new CmdQueueItem();
        m_queueItem.characteristic = ch;
        m_queueItem.dataToWrite    = dataToWrite;
        m_queueItem.writeWoRsp     = !requestResponse;
        m_queueItem.type           = m_queueItemType.WriteCharacteristic;
        EnqueueBleCommand(m_queueItem);
    }

    /* request to fetch newest value stored on the remote device for particular characteristic */
    public void EnqueueReadCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch)
    {
        // Add to queue because shitty Android GATT stuff is only synchronous
        CmdQueueItem m_queueItem = new CmdQueueItem();
        m_queueItem.characteristic = ch;
        m_queueItem.type = m_queueItemType.ReadCharacteristic;
        EnqueueBleCommand(m_queueItem);
    }

    /**
     * Add a transaction item to transaction queue
     * @param m_queueItem
     */
    private void EnqueueBleCommand(CmdQueueItem m_queueItem)
    {
        m_cmdQueue.add(m_queueItem);

        // If there is no other transmission processing, go do this one!
        if (!m_cmdQueueProcessing)
            ProcessCmdQueue();
    }

    /**
     * Call when a transaction has been completed.
     * Will process next transaction if queued
     */
    private void ProcessCmdQueue()
    {
        if (m_cmdQueue.size() <= 0)
        {
            m_cmdQueueProcessing = false;
            return;
        }

        m_cmdQueueProcessing = true;
        CmdQueueItem m_queueItem = m_cmdQueue.remove();

        switch (m_queueItem.type)
        {
            case WriteCharacteristic:
                writeDataToCharacteristic(m_queueItem.characteristic, m_queueItem.dataToWrite, m_queueItem.writeWoRsp);
                break;

            case SubscribeCharacteristic:
                setNotificationForCharacteristic(m_queueItem.characteristic, m_queueItem.enabled);
                break;

            case ReadCharacteristic:
                requestCharacteristicValue(m_queueItem.characteristic);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void requestCharacteristicValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch)
    {
        if (m_bluetoothGatt == null)
            return;

        m_bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(ch);
    }

    private void writeDataToCharacteristic(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, final byte[] dataToWrite, boolean writeWoRsp)
    {
        if (m_bluetoothGatt == null || ch == null)
            return;

        ch.setValue(dataToWrite);
        ch.setWriteType(writeWoRsp ? BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE : BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        m_bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(ch);
    }

    /* enables/disables notification for characteristic */
    private void setNotificationForCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, boolean enabled)
    {
        if (m_bluetoothGatt == null || ch == null)
            return;

        ch.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        boolean success = m_bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(ch, enabled);
        if(success)
        {
            // This is also sometimes required (e.g. for heart rate monitors) to enable notifications/indications
            // see: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = ch.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
            if(descriptor != null)
            {
                if (enabled)
                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                else
                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

                if (m_bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor))
                {
                    Log.i("BLE Peripheral", "SetNotification (Set + CCC) succeeded!");
                }
            }
            else
                Log.i("BLE Peripheral", "SetNotification (Set only) succeeded!");
        }
        else
            Log.e("BLE Peripheral", "SetNotification failed!");
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Abstract methods

    protected abstract boolean SetupDevice(BluetoothGatt gatt);
    protected abstract void    OnUpdate(UUID service, UUID characteristic, final byte[] value);
}
```

**Code to create and connect to a device**

```java
BleCentral central = new BleCentral();
m_customDevice     = central.Connect(this, deviceMacAddress, () -> new CustomDevice());
```

CustomDevice is just inheriting the BlePeripheral class, implementing SetupDevice (that checks that all services and characteristics are there) and OnUpdate (that receives new data and handles it).

Now, two things bother me:

- When connecting to the device, sometimes it works right away, and sometimes not. If not, I have to go connect to the device through another app such as Bluefruit Connect, then start my app again, and then it will connect ;
- When it connects, it goes through service discovery and all, and in the setNotificationForCharacteristic function everything gets called correctly (I get onDescriptorWrite called and all) but I never receive any notification.

Since I'm the one behind the code running on my BLE peripheral, I can guarantee that the characteristic I'm trying to get data from is of the NOTIFY type (and not e.g. INDICATE).

If it can help in any way, the only NOTIFY characteristic there is sends a 56-byte array filled with 14 floats as often as it can. Early prototypes with Web Bluetooth or NativeScript (with the nativescript-bluetooth plugin) showed me that this actually works and in these cases I get results roughly about every 90 milliseconds.

I think I've rewritten this code about 3 times already and I'm getting a bit desperate, so any help going in the right direction is appreciated. :D

Thanks a lot!

***Edit***: Just for science, I tried to switch the characteristic to a READ one on the device, then spawning a thread reading it every second, instead of waiting for notifications. Well, onCharacteristicRead is called, but the byte array passed to it always has a length of zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - it was not related to the Java code at all but caused by a hardware fault in my BLE device that caused all value updates to be discarded.